# ASP.Net Web Site running in IIS - change to ASP.Net Development Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7

My client gave me this web solution, in it various projects, and the problematic project (for me) is the Web Site.

I've copied the code to test web server (2008) and installed VS 2008 so I could step through the code on the server due to some weirdness.

Anyhow, when I open the solution locally on my personal computer, it runs on Cassini (http://localhost:3452/MyApp) because I'm not on a server OS.  However, when I run the app on the web server, when I hit F5, it runs oh http://localhost/MyApp.

When I'm running the code on the server, how do I point the web site to use Cassini?

Thanks for your help in advance!
tperri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web tab of the project settings, you should be able to specify which web server to use. However, there is no need to change the server for debugging - simply attach the debugger (Debug/Attach to Process) to w3wp.exe.

Comment: I'm not seeing any tabs?  I right click on the web site and select "property pages" and see a windows, left nav menu of "References, Build, Accessibility, Start Options and MSBuild options"+

Also, the w3wp.exe process does not appear when I bring up the Debug/Attach to Process dialog.

thanks for your help Tom

Comment: OK, I have determined there is no .proj file.  the project is A Web Site, not a Web Project, so i'm not sure where to fix this setting.

Comment: w3wp.exe will only appear if IIS is running and you have it set to show processes from all users.

I haven't used the old web site format in several years, so I'm not sure where the options are for that. However, in most cases there shouldn't be any problems upgrading it to a web project.